# Why do my foor-loop give the value null to my created variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, null

Im trying to connect my todo-with my calender. Im looping through all my tables of calender and then looping through my array of todos.

And then it should add a circle with countTodo inside it, that says how many todos i have that day.

But i get an error when im in my first IF-statement, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"

I have checked and my "tds[j]" is null. I dont know why and dont know how to fix it.

```
function checkArrayWithCalendar() {
    let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td")

    for (let j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {

        let secondDivInCalendar = tds[j].querySelector("#todoInCalendar")
        let countTodo = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
            if (tds[j].firstElementChild.innerText == todos[i].date) {
                countTodo++
            }
        }

        if (countTodo > 0) {

            if (!secondDivInCalendar) {
                secondDivInCalendar = document.createElement("div")
                secondDivInCalendar.id = "todoInCalendar"
                tds[j].appendChild(secondDivInCalendar)

                let spanForArray = document.createElement("span")
                spanForArray.classList = "spanForArray"
                secondDivInCalendar.appendChild(spanForArray)
            }
            secondDivInCalendar.firstElementChild.innerText = countTodo
        }
    }
}
```

https://1974pontus.github.io/Todo-kalender/ 
Here is the link to the todo.

What do i do wrong and why is it my .innerText null?

this is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/edc24130b8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:75.43em)" href="stylesheet/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:49.5em) and (max-width:75.43em)" href="stylesheet/tablet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:49.5em)" href="stylesheet/mobile.css">


    <title>TODO</title>
</head>

<body>



    <div class="content-wrapper">


        <div class="todo-wrapper">
            <div class="header"><img src="Title2.png" alt="title" srcset=""></div>
            <div class="todo-title">
                <h1 id="day"></h1>
                <h4 id="Time"></h4>
                <h4 id="dateOfToday"></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="todo-list-wrapper">
                <div class="inputAndButton">
                    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Vad är på din agenda?">
                    <select name="date" id="Date">
                        <option value="">Date:</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <i id="add-icon" class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="todoList">
                    <ul id="listForAllTodos">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hej">
            <div class="card">
                <h2 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sun</th>
                            <th>Mon</th>
                            <th>Tue</th>
                            <th>Wed</th>
                            <th>Thu</th>
                            <th>Fri</th>
                            <th>Sat</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="calendar-body">

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="form-inline">

                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="previous"
                        onclick="previous()">Previous</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="next" onclick="next()">Next</button>
                </div>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Jump To: </label>
                    <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">
                        <option value=0>Jan</option>
                        <option value=1>Feb</option>
                        <option value=2>Mar</option>
                        <option value=3>Apr</option>
                        <option value=4>May</option>
                        <option value=5>Jun</option>
                        <option value=6>Jul</option>
                        <option value=7>Aug</option>
                        <option value=8>Sep</option>
                        <option value=9>Oct</option>
                        <option value=10>Nov</option>
                        <option value=11>Dec</option>
                    </select>


                    <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year"
                        onchange="jump()">
                        <option value=1990>1990</option>
                        <option value=1991>1991</option>
                        <option value=1992>1992</option>
                        <option value=1993>1993</option>
                        <option value=1994>1994</option>
                        <option value=1995>1995</option>
                        <option value=1996>1996</option>
                        <option value=1997>1997</option>
                        <option value=1998>1998</option>
                        <option value=1999>1999</option>
                        <option value=2000>2000</option>
                        <option value=2001>2001</option>
                        <option value=2002>2002</option>
                        <option value=2003>2003</option>
                        <option value=2004>2004</option>
                        <option value=2005>2005</option>
                        <option value=2006>2006</option>
                        <option value=2007>2007</option>
                        <option value=2008>2008</option>
                        <option value=2009>2009</option>
                        <option value=2010>2010</option>
                        <option value=2011>2011</option>
                        <option value=2012>2012</option>
                        <option value=2013>2013</option>
                        <option value=2014>2014</option>
                        <option value=2015>2015</option>
                        <option value=2016>2016</option>
                        <option value=2017>2017</option>
                        <option value=2018>2018</option>
                        <option value=2019>2019</option>
                        <option value=2020>2020</option>
                        <option value=2021>2021</option>
                        <option value=2022>2022</option>
                        <option value=2023>2023</option>
                        <option value=2024>2024</option>
                        <option value=2025>2025</option>
                        <option value=2026>2026</option>
                        <option value=2027>2027</option>
                        <option value=2028>2028</option>
                        <option value=2029>2029</option>
                        <option value=2030>2030</option>
                    </select>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="todo.js" defer></script>
    <script src="calendar.js" defer></script>


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your html code too

Comment: done, but im creating my td's in javascript in another file.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("td")` will select `td` elements in the document but there aren't any. Try with `th` elements instead, like `let tds = document.querySelectorAll("th")`

Comment: No difference... still same error. if i `console.log(tds[j])` its only the first box coming. Its like its not looping through and getting stuck at `tds[0]`

Comment: what are you trying to get from `tds[j].querySelector("#todoInCalendar")`?

Comment: Solved it. Had to add an if-statement `if (tds[j].firstElementChild != null) {

                for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {

                    if (tds[j].firstElementChild.innerText == todos[i].date) {
                        countTodo++
                    }
                }
            }` Thanks for the help